# Plural forms of gerunds

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, inflectional-morphology, gerund-phrases, deverbal-nouns

In this sentence, the noun *savings* is in plural form:

> I have one **savings** account.

It is **like** a gerund or maybe it **is** a gerund, I am not clear about
it. But when I searched the Internet, I found somewhere claiming that a
gerund is always singular, but somewhere else claiming that some gerunds do
have plural forms.

I am confused. As far as I understand it, saying that a gerund is a verbal
noun means that it **is** a verb as well as a noun at the same time, but that
it is also **not** a noun.

The Internet suggests that gerunds iwth plural forms like *drawings*,
*meanings* , and so one do not seem to be gerunds at all but they do seem
to be nouns.

I want to know:

1. Do gerunds have plural forms?  If so, could you please give me some examples?
2. Are the nouns *drawing*, *meaning*, etc. actually really gerunds, or are 
   they actually really nouns?
3. What is the difference between a gerund and a noun?

Comment: Although note that in _savings account/s_, 'savings' is used as a plural-form (-s) attributive; this models more on 'systems manager' than -*ing**-form usages. It's best to regard 'savings account' as a compound noun, and, if you must, 'savings' here as being deverbal and plural in form.

Comment: The best advice is to forget you ever heard the word *gerund*. Much of what you read on the Internet is simply wrong about this.  A gerund is **not** a part of speech but rather a particular type of syntactic relation a certain kind of ***nonfinite clause*** can fulfil. The only parts of speech that matter here are nouns, verbs, and adjectives, so whenever you see an *-ing* word, you should decide which one of those three parts of speech it is. Note also that POS categories are highlander ones: “There can be only one.”

Comment: "A Grammar of  Contemporary English" by Randolph Quirk give a very helpful guide to the "-ing" form at p124 (if you can tolerate a few scanning errors). That section ends with "In this book we shall disregard the distinction between gerund and participle,"  

A copy can be found at https://studyres.com/doc/524405/a-grammar-of-contemporary-english

Comment: "Savings" can't be a gerund, because gerunds are verbs, and verbs don't have plural forms.  Here, it's a noun, the first part of the compound noun "savings account".

Comment: @GregLee That's right: nonfinite verbs have no plurals in English. That said, **finite** verbs actually do have plural forms—I think. One at least does so. Certainly *is/are* and *was/were* count as an existence proof albeit for that most unusual of verbs in our language, but quite possibly also the rest like *does/do* as well depending on what you think of the base form.

Comment: @tchrist, Well, surely no one would regard the -z verb inflection as a plural suffix.

Answer (score 1):

**Saving** is used as

(i) A participle: "He was saving me time."

(ii) A gerund "Saving now will benefit you later."

(iii) A verbal noun: "The saving of the ship cost 20 lives." /There is a saving of $5 if you buy now.

OED

> Saving (n.) 5c. A sum of money set aside or kept in reserve. Now usually in plural: money accumulated by economizing or by setting aside (esp. on a regular basis) a portion of one's income.

Savings is a verbal noun

A verbal noun differs from a gerund in that it is qualified by an adjective (as in common nouns, of which it is part) and may have a plural form.

Comment: No; 'savings' is (at least getting towards) a deverbal noun. Note that 'the saving of the ship' does not pluralise; one would speak (awkwardly) of 'the saving of HMS Pyramid and SS Sphynx', not the savings. 'Multiple savings [can be made ...]' show countification taking place in one of the financial subsenses (I think one has to speak of multiple savings accounts).